# Build R vignette using devtools::build()

Tags: r, devtools, vignette

I am trying to build some vignettes in my R package MDP2 https://github.com/relund/mdp. If I from RStudio run `devtools::build_vignettes()` everything compiles fine. However, if I use `devtools::build()` or `devtools::install_github("relund/mdp", build_vignettes = TRUE)` I get the error below. Any ideas why?

```
* checking for file 'C:\Users\larsrn\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGK46CV\devtoolsd88e8236d\relund-mdp-035d61b/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'MDP2':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
* installing the package to build vignettes
* creating vignettes ...Warning: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.4/bin/x64/Rscript" --vanilla --default-packages= -e "tools::buildVignettes(dir = '.', tangle = TRUE)"' had status 1
 ERROR
Error: file 'C:/Users/larsrn/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpiGWXE2/Rbuild9a06d8d6a6c/MDP2/DESCRIPTION' is not in valid DCF format
In addition: Warning message:
In read.dcf(dfile, keep.white = .keep_white_description_fields) :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:/Users/larsrn/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpiGWXE2/Rbuild9a06d8d6a6c/MDP2/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'Permission denied'
Execution halted

sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Danish_Denmark.1252  LC_CTYPE=Danish_Denmark.1252    LC_MONETARY=Danish_Denmark.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Danish_Denmark.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] diagram_1.6.3 shape_1.4.2   knitr_1.12.3  MDP2_2.0.0    plyr_1.8.3    Rcpp_0.12.3  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] codetools_0.2-14 withr_1.0.1      digest_0.6.9     R6_2.1.2         git2r_0.14.0     formatR_1.3     
 [7] magrittr_1.5     evaluate_0.8.3   httr_1.1.0       stringi_1.0-1    curl_0.9.6       rmarkdown_0.9.5 
[13] devtools_1.10.0  tools_3.2.4      stringr_1.0.0    yaml_2.1.13      memoise_1.0.0    htmltools_0.3
```

Comment: Does R CMD build work if you call it directly from command prompt?

Comment: Same error as above :-(

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you find a solution?